# Centralized logrotate Container for all containers in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, logrotate

My logrotate container gives me following errors:

```
error: Ignoring activity_logs because it is writable by group or others.
error: Ignoring httpd because it is writable by group or others.
error: Ignoring reminder_cron because it is writable by group or others.
```

`activity_logs` and `reminder_cron` are present in `/opt/logs` directory, wheras `httpd` is present inside `/var/log/httpd`

Following are the permissions of the folders, when mounted inside `logrotate` container:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            64 Aug 27 04:08 logs
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root            64 Sep  1 20:45 httpd
```

Logrotate runs with `root` user

I am trying to setup centralized logrotate for all my docker containers.
Following is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  server:
    image: private-apache:latest
    command: /usr/sbin/apachectl -DFOREGROUND
    ports:
      - "XXXX:XXXX"
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
      - ./opt:/opt
      - ./logs/httpd:/var/log/httpd
      - ./data/tmp:/tmp
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
      - beanstalkd
      - rsyslog
    restart: always

  logrotate:
    image: private-logrotate:latest
    command: /usr/sbin/crond -f
    volumes:
      - ./logs/rsyslog/var/log:/var/log
      - ./opt/logs:/opt/logs
      - ./logs/httpd:/var/log/httpd
    restart: always

  rsyslog:
    image: private-rsyslog:latest
    ports:
      - "XXX:XXX"
    volumes:
      - ./logs/rsyslog/var/log:/var/log
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - logrotate

  mysql:
    image: private-mysql:latest
    privileged: false
    ports:
      - "XXXX:XXXX"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/tmp:/tmp
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=databasename
    restart: always

  redis:
      image: private-redis:latest
      ports:
        - "XXXX:XXXX"
      volumes:
        - ./data/redis:/var/lib/redis
      restart: always

  beanstalkd:
      image: private-beanstalkd:latest
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "XXXX:XXXX"
```

The `server` container and `rsyslog` container generate logs with different users. `logrotate` container has no idea about those users, hence putting `su` inside `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd`,`/etc/logrotate.d/activity_log` and `/etc/logrotate.d/reminder_cron` is not possible.
I would like to know is it possible to force logrotate to ignore these errors and rotate the logs from mounted volumes.
Or is there any better way fo doing this.

The idea is to have a central logrotate for all the containers